# CM to INCH Converting Program Python

Tags: python

Hello i am trying to make a converting program but i can't get it to work, I am going to convert multiply different things but i start with CM to INCH. I get error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'.
Here is some of the code:

```
   print('Press the number of the one you want to convert: ')
   number = input()
   inch = float(2.54)
   if number == '1':
       print('How many inch? ')
       print('There are %s'.format(number / inch))

Here is the whole code:

print('Welcome to the converting program')
print('What of these do you want to convert?')
print(  "\nHow many centimeters in inches? 1"
    "\nHow many milliliters in a pint? 2"
    "\nHow many acres in a square-mile? 3"
    "\nHow many pounds in a metric ton? 4"
    "\nHow many calories in a BTU? 5")

print('Press the number of the one you want to convert: ')

number = float(input()) 

inch = float(2.54)
if number == '1':
    print('How many inch? ')
    print('There are {0}'.format(number / inch))

elif number == '2':
    print('millimeters')

elif number == '3':
    print('acres')

elif number == '4':
    print('pounds')

elif number == '5':
    print('calories')
```

Answer (score 1):

%s is the notation for formatting a string, %f should be used for floats. In newer versions of python however you should use {0}

```
print('There are {0}'.format(number / inch))
```

Read [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) for more information on this.

Further to this, as Sebastian Hietsch mentioned in his answer, your input variable is a string that will need to be converted to a float first. Do this before your formatting expression.

```
number = float(input())
inch = float(2.54)
```

You may want to add some error handling:

```
try:
    number = float(input())
except TypeError as e:
    print('input must be a float')
inch = float(2.54)
```

Of course, you will need to remove the quotes from the '1' in the if statement.

Comment: Here is the code now number = float(input()) 

inch = float(2.54)
if number == '1':
    print('How many inch? ')
    print('There are {0}'.format(number / inch))                                     Still getting operand error for some reason

Comment: @C9Fox check the edit; you will now need to remove the quotes on the if statement. I.e: if number == 1:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `number` is a string and you can't perform mathematical operations on it. What you'll need to do is convert it to an integer or a float using `int(number)` or `float(number)`.
So you could do: `print("There are ℅f".format(float(number)/inch))`